# Use Arduino to Plot the balance of my airplane propeller using optical sensor and reflective tape

Tags: arduino, balancing

I would like to use an arduino to determine how out of balance my airplane propeller is.  I've seen a production device that uses an optical sensor and reflective tape to plot this.  Can this be done with an arduino, and if so, what would I need to do it?

Comment: First, determine the working-principle of the tape/sensor implementation. Then figure out what type of computation and I/O you'll need (do you have to measure voltages, for example?). Lastly, write all of that information down and determine if the microcontroller (AVR, in this case) has the necessary peripherals and speed (if necessary) to do what you need. You are asking a pretty broad question here and it will likely close.

Comment: Questions get closed if it is too vague. Also people like to see evidence that the questioner (e.g. you) have done some work, and are *not* asking for information that they could get themselves by doing some www research using a search engine. For advice about how to ask questions which are likely to receive answers take the [tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) or look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Arduino is a brand of products, using the common programming IDE - they have tiny 8-bit microcontrollers up to very powerful ARM Cortex M3/4 products available.

Answer (score 1):

The optical sensor is not sufficient. It works in conjunction with an accelerometer to measure the actual imbalance. An Arduino should be able to control the two sensors and have the results displayed. Interesting little project. Btw, the reflector will cause an imbalance itself when attached to the propeller; this should be compensated in some way.